# Adding lists of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3],'b':['ABC-1|ABD-5'],'c':[2],'d':[1],'e':[1],'f':[8]})

In [3]: columns = ['b','f']

In [4]: df_dict = df[columns].to_dict(orient='records')

In [5]: df_dict
Out[5]: [{'b': 'ABC-1|ABD-5', 'f': 8}]

In [6]: df_dict2 = df[['c']].to_dict(orient='records')

In [7]: df_dict2
Out[8]: [{'c': 2}]
```

How do I combine `df_dict` and `df_dict2` such that the end result is:

```
[{'b': 'ABC-1|ABD-5', 'f': 8, 'c':2}]
```

Given that they're lists, I tried `df_dict.append(df_dict2)` but it just gives:

```
[{'b': 'ABC-1|ABD-5', 'f': 8},[{'c': 2}]]
```

Any advice/suggestions/ideas?

Comment: `df_dict.update(df_dict2)`

Comment: Are the pandas dataframes relevant to the question? You're just operating on dictionaries, not dataframes.

Comment: @rafaelc  `df_dict` and `df_dict2` are lists

Comment: Yeah I need to grab columns from a dataframe so I added that in by way of saying "I have this constraint and that's why I'm using df[columns].to_dict"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the contents of the dictionary within `df_dict` with the contents of the dictionary in `df_dict2`

```
df_dict[0].update(df_dict2[0])
```